# Setting ruby version separately with different app on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, chruby

I have just started working on a ruby project and I notice that I have to specify the ruby version to use globally. For instance, I am using [chruby](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/12.html) to change the ruby version to use and I can set it directly at this file called **.zshrc**.

But if I have a multiple apps with different ruby version, then how do I handle it? It doesn't make sense if I keep changing the version to use at **.zshrc** file every time I want to run the other app.

Since it's a shared project so I cannot just change the version used in the app. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `chruby`, this feature is called "Auto-switching".

> If you want chruby to auto-switch the current version of Ruby when you cd between your different projects, simply load auto.sh in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc:
>
> ..
>
> chruby will check the current and parent directories for a .ruby-version file.
>
> https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#auto-switching

Comment: I guess I missed this out. Thank you for pointing it!